# python multiprocessing - suspend worker function until queue has another data to process

Tags: python, queue, multiprocessing

I have little problem understanding python multiprocessing. I wrote an application, witch analyzes downloaded web pages. I would like to fetch raw html in separate process with specific timeout. I know i can set timeout in urllib2, but it seems not working correctly in some cases when using socks5 proxy.
So, wrote a little Class:

```
class SubprocessManager(Logger):

    def __init__(self, function):
        self.request_queue = Queue()
        self.return_queue = Queue()
        self.worker = function
        self.args = ()
        self.kwargs = {'request_queue': self.request_queue,
                       'return_queue': self.return_queue}
        self._run()

    def _run(self):
        self.subprocess = Process(target=self.worker, args=self.args, kwargs=self.kwargs)
        self.subprocess.start()

    def put_in_queue(self, data):
        self.request_queue.put(data)

    def get_from_queue(self):
        result = None
        try:
            result = self.request_queue.get(timeout=10)
        except Empty:
            self.reset_process()
        return result

    def reset_process(self):
        if self.subprocess.is_alive():
            self.subprocess.terminate()
        self._run()
```

Worker function:

```
def subprocess_fetch_www(*args, **kwargs):

    request_queue = kwargs['request_queue']
    return_queue = kwargs['return_queue']
    while True:
        request_data = request_queue.get()
        if request_data:
            return_data = fetch_request(*request_data)
            return_queue.put(return_data)
```

And function that is called for each url from input list:

```
def fetch_html(url, max_retry=cfg.URLLIB_MAX_RETRY, to_xml=False, com_headers=False):

    subprocess = Logger.SUBPROCESS
    args = (url, max_retry, com_headers)
    subprocess.put_in_queue(args)
    result = subprocess.get_from_queue()

    if result and to_xml:
        return html2lxml(result)
    return result
```

I need help in fixing my code. I want my subprocess running all the time waiting for job in request_queue. I want to recreate subprocess only in case of timeout. Worker should suspend execution once request_data is processed and return_data put in return queue.

How can i achieve that?

EDIT:

Well, it seems that above code works as intended, if `get_from_queue` requests result data from `return_queue` instead `request_queue`... >_>'

Comment: I think you want to also recreate the queues in `reset_process` - that way you'll know that `request_queue` is empty before you enqueue an new message for the worker process.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I think I have a better understanding of what you want to do.

Have a look at this code. It's not OO but illustrates the idea.

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue, Pipe
from time import sleep
import random

proc = None
inq = None
outq = None

def createWorker():
  global inq, outq, proc
  inq = Queue()
  outq = Queue()
  proc = Process(target=worker, args=(inq,outq))
  proc.start()

def worker(inq, outq):
  print "Worker started"
  while True:
    url = inq.get()
    secs = random.randint(1,5)
    print "processing", url, " sleeping for", secs
    sleep(secs)
    outq.put(url + " done")

def callWithTimeout(arg):
  global proc, inq, outq
  inq.put(arg)
  result = None
  while result is None:
    try:
      result = outq.get(timeout=4)
    except:
      print "restarting worker process"
      proc.terminate()
      createWorker()
      inq.put(arg)
  return result

def main():
  global proc, inq, outq
  createWorker()

  for arg in ["foo", "bar", "baz", "quux"]:
    res = callWithTimeout(arg)
    print "res =", res

  proc.terminate()

main()
```

It uses two queues - one for sending messages to the worker process and one for receiving the results. You could also use pipes. Also, new queues are created when the worker process is restarted - this is to avoid a possible race condition.

Edit: Just saw your edit - looks like the same idea.

Comment: I managed to implement suggested solution before - where new process is spawned for worker function to do it's job and it terminates once it's done.

Comment: But isn't it inefficient to start and terminate new process each second for large amount of urls to fetch? Wouldn't it be more optimal to start one process that might survive whole running time (in case timeout never occur)?